# Using regular expressions to remove space between stand-alone characters in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a vector of characters in R and I want to use regular expressions to pull out a certain pattern. I would like to find occurrences where there are two or more stand-alone letters in a row. This can occur either within a longer string or at the beginning of the longer string. I would then like to remove the space between these letters. I want to keep the space if it does not occur between two stand-alone letters. Below are a couple examples of what I am looking for.

If the vector was:

```
v <- c("A B C", "ABC D E", "A BC D E FH", "A B CDE")
```

"A B C" should become "ABC"

"ABC D E" should become "ABC DE"

"A BC D E FH" should become "A BC DE FH"

"A B CDE" should become "AB CDE"

So that the resulting vector after I remove the spacing is:

```
c("ABC", "ABC DE", "A BC DE FH", "AB CDE")
```

There is no punctuation in the vector, and all the letters are capitalized.

What I have done to locate them already is:

```
grep("^[A-Z] [A-Z] ", v)
grep(" [A-Z] [A-Z] ", v)
```

However, I would like to do this in one step if possible and take into account that a string might end with a stand-alone character. I am not sure how to use `gsub`to delete only the spaces between the characters.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/xB0zG5/2

Comment: Just a note: I also came up with [`gsub("(?:(?<=\\b[A-Z]) )?(\\b[A-Z]\\b)", "\\1", v, perl=T)`](http://ideone.com/rsxwd8).